# AES-CTR and AES-CMAC using the same temporary key

Tags: encryption, aes, authentication, ctr, cmac

Is it a severe security issue using a *short-lived dynamic key* for both AES-CTR and AES-CMAC?

CMAC is generated on the cleartext and 32 bit of it are attached to the message (MAC-and-Encrypt)

The key exchange ensures that dynamic key and NONCE values are never in the clear on the wire.